# Java P2P networking, using same port for different inbound and outbound connections

Tags: java, sockets, p2p, bittorrent

I am implementing a peer to peer networking application which involves sending an initial handshake to all the peers and thereafter communicating asynchronously while listening on a particular port. Therefore, I first need to send the handshakes to different peers using the same port which my application will be listening to thereafter. I have had some confusion on whether we can bind two different sockets to the same local port or not but it gives me a bind exception. I am not sure how this can be done.

Comment: You tagged this as bittorrent. how is your question specific to bittorrent? Bittorrent does not mandate anything about the local port for outgoing connections.

Comment: @the8472 - what I am implementing is actually a bittorrent application and from the docs, what i know is that I have to listen to a single port. So, I have to do a handshake from a port same as the one i have announced to the tracker, how can i do that if i am to initiate the handshake for all the peers whose addresses i have received from the tracker? Or am i supposed to use a different port for each p2p connection while i am initiating the handshake?

Comment: Also, what i want to know is that, if a 4 tuple unique combination is all that you need to have a connection, how can you implement that, given that i am using the same port for all those tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets must have unique `<source address, source port, protocol (tcp/udp), destination address, destination port>` tuples.

So yes, it's possible to re-use local ports by setting the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option to true as long as the remote addresses are distinct.

But this is not necessary. The bittorrent protocol does not require that the local port of outgoing connections is set to any particular port. You don't have to bind outgoing connections at all. You can simply let the TCP stack figure out the correct interface and port.

Only your listening socket needs to be bound to the port which you announce. No particular address needed either, you can use the [unspecified address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Unspecified_address), `::0` (for v4/v6 dual stack sockets) or `0.0.0.0` (v4 only).

> so, I have to do a handshake from a port same as the one i have announced to the tracker

the spec does not say that anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! I was mistaken about the port requirement.